# Executing scripts in terminal

Tags: bash

So instead of wanting to navigate to the location of a script and run ./script.sh, I would like to be able to type "script" from anywhere and have that run. I think this can be done by putting the scripts in /usr/bin or /etc/init.d right? In which case, how would I go about this when I don't have root access over the machine? Is there a personal directory within /home/me that I can put scripts in to achieve this?

Running Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you add `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` and place your scripts in there.